# singleton WCF service in C#

Tags: wcf, singleton

I'm developing an application in C#. I have created ServiceHost app which will host the wcf service.
client will call ServiceHost.exe by passing some argument.
I have tried by below way.

```
static class ServiceHost
   {
      private static ITest channel = null;

     static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (String.Compare(args[0], "dooperation", true) == 0) 
               {
                    NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.Transport);
                    binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
                    EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress(address);

                   channel = ChannelFactory<ITest>.CreateChannel(binding, ep);

                   channel.DoOpertion1();
                   channel.Close() // close service

                   // Make sure the application runs!
                   Application.Run();
                   GC.KeepAlive(m_singleInstance);
               }
              else if (String.Compare(args[0], "stop", true) == 0) 
               {
                    NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.Transport);

                    binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
                    EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress(address);

                   channel = ChannelFactory<ITest>.CreateChannel(binding, ep);

                   channel.DoOpertion2();

                   channel.Close() // close service
            // Exit Appli
                    Application.Exit(); 
               }
        }
   }
```

So here  I'm creating communication channel, calling method and closing the channel.
but creating namepipe, then communication channel and service channel consuming more time, so i want to optimize the call so that it will create single instance of WCF service communication channel whenever client calls ServiceHost.exe.

is there any way to create single instance of channel?
is there any side effect if we keep open the namepine/communication channel.

Answer (score 0):

Reusing a WCF channel is an anti pattern, the channel is not thread safe and you have to handle the fault state. The creation of the channel is not time consuming, the creation of the factory is. So you should reuse your ChannelFactory.

[MSDN Middle-Tier Client Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738757.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please share code to reuse channel factory.